# Storage reliable measurement standard for sd card, sata hard disk, ssd hard disk

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata, sd-card, pata

Is there a measurement standard that measure the reliability for the following storage devices:

- sd card
  [image]
- sata hard disk (regardless 2.5 or 3.5 inch)
  [image]
- ssd hard disk (regardless 2.5 or 3.5 inch)
  [image]

From my understanding, both the sd card and the ssd hard disk reliability is measure by the number of writes while the sata hard disk is measure by the total number of hours before they fail to store data.

So, it there a standard measurement method that I can measure the reliability across the different kinds of storage devices (probably also include other storage devices such as IDE hard disk)?

Comment: Reliability indicator common to all these different storage device types? I doubt there's one.

Comment: The reliability is 100% dependent on the flash used in these devices.  Why are you mucking up a good question by adding in mechanical devices, which has nothing to do with the reliability of flash devices.